# How to hold and change big object in react App without redux?

Tags: reactjs

I need to design an app like a html editor, but the result it produces is an config object rather than HTML code. This object is a deeply nested object, like DOM element, it contains size, color,location, children elements and any other properties. User will do some operations frequently and pass the the config object to generate a dialog to preview the result at any time.

In order to improve the performance, we indeed should avoid make the whole config object as a state of the HOC container component. We need get some properties of it to consist a state. Although we can change the config object while the state is changing, but the data retrieval in a deeply nested object recursively maybe cause performance issues.

Although we can do these changes asynchronously, but any time the user can open the dialog with the calculation result, we cannot make sure these asynchronous operations has finished.

If we use redux, we can generate a new config object while user fire the action to open the dialog, but without redux, the state tree is not easy to do like this.

Any one has good suggestions for this app?

Comment: Why don't you use redux ?

Comment: Actually we want to make thins simple to just use the new context API, we find the redux only have a store, and it lead to create reducer, action creator and container components for a HOC.